# How to set repeater control back colour by item index?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, powerpacks

I am using a [`DataRepeater`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.datarepeater.aspx) control to show a popup. I am able to set `BackColor` of the current item by this code

```
private void dataRepeater1_CurrentItemIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dataRepeater1.CurrentItem.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

but I am unable to add `BackColor` white for the previous item. Also I want to change the `BackColor` of the item form the list I am hovering mouse.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to have one more property in your class, maybe called `DataRepeater1_PreviousItem`:

```
class YourClass
{
    DataRepeaterItem DataRepeater1_PreviousItem { get; set; }

    // ... some other code

    private void dataRepeater1_CurrentItemIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataRepeater1_PreviousItem != null)
            DataRepeater1_PreviousItem.BackColor = Color.White;

        dataRepeater1.CurrentItem.BackColor = Color.Red;

        DataRepeater1_PreviousItem = dataRepeater1.CurrentItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing called previous item.

Comment: @Shankha indeed, you have to add that new property to your class. You can name it anything you want. `DataRepeater1_PreviousItem` was just an example.

Comment: Please help me to add. I understand the concept

Comment: @Shanka I'm not exactly sure what can I do to help, but I updated the code to make it more clear.

Comment: @Shanka if this answer is the accepted answer for the question then you should accept it by clicking the hollow check mark next to the answer, so that it becomes green.

Comment: I have done it in a different way. I have used devexpress grid in place of data repeater.

Comment: @Shanka that's great. It would be nice if you would describe the solution as an answer to your own question, and then accept that answer so that the question becomes answered, so that other people could find it useful.